# Get a string when running an object class through str.replace(obj_cls, "new string")

Tags: python, python-2.7, object, repr, object-class

I have an object class:

```
class Color(object):
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color
```

I want to run the following commands:

```
blue = Color("blue")

print blue
"The pen is {}".format(blue)
"The pen is blue".replace(blue, "red")
```

This returns:

```
# <__main__.Color object at 0x000001A527675908>
# The pen is <__main__.Color object at 0x000001A527675908>

# # Original exception was:
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 2, in <module>
# TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object #
```

I can fix the print and format by including `repr` to the class.

```
class Color(object):
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.color

blue = Color("blue")

print blue
"The pen is {}".format(blue)
"The pen is blue".replace(blue, "red")

# blue
# The pen is blue

# # Original exception was:
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 2, in <module>
# TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object #
```

**How can I get the `replace` function to work with this object class?**

It works if I put a str() wrapper around the object class:

```
"The pen is blue".replace(str(blue), "red")
```

However I don't want to do it this way, as it would require a lot of special code support to function.

Comment: "The pen is blue".replace("blue", "red")

Comment: You can get your code to work if you make Color a subclass of string i.e. `class Color(str):`  Then: ``"The pen is blue".replace(blue, "red")` works.

Comment: @DarrylG, I did not know you could do that! That works for my needs, thank you. Could you put this as the answer, and I'll flag this as resolved. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to make your class a subclass of str.  This is similar to [How to make a class that acts like a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919644/how-to-make-a-class-that-acts-like-a-string)

**Modified Code**

```
class Color(str):
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.color
```

**Usage**

```
blue = Color("blue")
print("The pen is {}".format(blue))
print("The pen is blue".replace(blue, "red"))
```

**Output**

```
The pen is blue
The pen is red
```